# Creating a PDF File in a separate thread in iOS

Tags: ios, uikit

I am using `UIKit` in iOS to create a PDF file from various `XIB` files that I have used for the layout of the pretended file.

I can successfully generate a PDF file. However I am doing so in the main thread, I want to move it into a separate thread so that the UI will not "freeze".

I have attempted in doing so with GCD, but it didn't work, and it threw back some errors.

I have something like this:

```
[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];

__block NSData *pdfNote = nil;

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0),^{
    pdfNote = [self generatePdfFile];
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    });
});
```

The errors I see are:

```
failed to find PDF header: `%PDF' not found.
failed to find PDF header: `%PDF' not found.
failed to find PDF header: `%PDF' not found.
failed to find PDF header: `%PDF' not found.
2012-07-12 15:31:15.427 IrmaosPeixoto-CRM[7601:1a03] bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x3404d0: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...
1   _ZL17_WebTryThreadLockb
2   WebThreadLock
3   -[UITextView setFrame:]
4   UIViewCommonInitWithFrame
5   -[UIView initWithCoder:]
6   -[UIScrollView initWithCoder:]
7   -[UITextView initWithCoder:]
8   UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue
9   UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue
10  -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:]
11  -[UIView initWithCoder:]
12  -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:]
13  UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue
14  -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:]
15  -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
16  UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue
17  UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue
18  -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:]
19  -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]
20  -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:]
21  +[UIView(Extensions) loadFromNib:owner:]
22  -[FinishOrderViewController generatePdfFile]
23  __43-[FinishOrderViewController buttonPressed:]_block_invoke_0
24  _dispatch_call_block_and_release
25  _dispatch_worker_thread2
26  _pthread_wqthread
27  start_wqthread
```

Additional notes:
The PDF generation involves some accesses to Core Data to fetch some info.

Is there a better (working) way of achieving what I need?

**EDIT** I was mistaken, I am using `UIKit` instead of core graphics to generate the PDF.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on here, let alone what the problem might be. Can you add more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are loading things from a XIB file, load the element within the bundle in the main thread.

I was able to successfully produce a PDF file just by loading the elements within the NSBundle in the main thread and then running everything in another thread.